# Ajax jquery url access denied in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ci_practice/blog/reviews',
        data: 'res_id='+res_id,
        success: function(data){
            $('#screen-overlay').show(slow);
            $('#screen-overlay').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

This throws me a 500 error. There is a problem in accessing the function `reviews` as shown by `console.log(xhr.responseText);` in console.

How should i assign value to url in ajax to perform this in a codeigniter way.
I have jQuery in a different file : ajax.js

Will appreciate your response. Thank You.

Comment: a 500 error indicates the target file has an error; check your error log and go from there.

Comment: wrong path?  try with url: <?php echo base_url();  ?>blog/reviews. Is ci_practice your codeigniter project folder?

Comment: Yes it is unable to access the controller function directly!
There is no problem in controller function as i am just echoing out something for test.
Is there any syntax i need to follow to put the url correctly in ajax request?

Comment: @nevermind Yes it is the project folder. Problem is i can't use php tags in a .js file!

Comment: @Cruze check the `$config['csrf_protection']` in config.php and set it to `FALSE` if it's enabled.

Comment: @HashemQolami I need that feature to prevent any security issue!

Comment: Where did you use php in javascript? Did you solve it?

Comment: As @nevermind said using `<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog/reviews` will solve my problem if my jQuery function were in the head of my view file. But it is in a separate file so the problem is still there!

Comment: @Cruze I know, I just want you to give it a try and check whether or not the problem is solved.

Comment: But hey.. Now the error changes to this :
POST http://localhost/ci_practice/blog/reviews  jquery.js:8526
send jquery.js:8526
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7978
(anonymous function) home_js.js:14
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3074
elemData.handle
And no error code is received!

Comment: @Cruze, then just hard code that path, if just it is a problem? http://localhost/ci_practice/blog/reviews/. And, yes, since method is post...  Did you try: data: res_id? In your controller - do you check this var as $this->input->post('res_id'), or you expecting different results, if you know what i mean?

Comment: This just duplicates the path : http://localhost/ci_practice/localhost/ci_practice/blog/reviews

$this->input->post('res_id') is what i am trying to echo from my function.

Comment: What i tried is putting all jquery code in the php file and then using base_url/site_url. Still getting the same 500 error! Don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the CSRF enabled in my config file! But disabling it is a wrong step.

This link : [Codeigniter Ajax CSRF Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348383/codeigniter-ajax-csrf-problem) actually solved my problem.
Using this code :

```
var post_data = {
            'res_id' : res_id,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        };
```

This just adds a CSRF security key which is needed by default by every POST method while submitting due to CSRF Enabled.

Comment: As I mentioned, but you [said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388660/ajax-jquery-url-access-denied-in-codeigniter#comment-25244037): `I tried! No Luck!`

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it wasn't working by just disabling it :/

Answer (score 1):

You should contain the `base_url` with controller name `/` then function name you want to access

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controllername/function',
    data: 'res_id='+res_id,
    success: function(data){
        $('#screen-overlay').show(slow);
        $('#screen-overlay').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```

});

in you case i think `blog` is the controller and `reviews` is a function so it should look like this `url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/blog/reviews',`

For Forbidden Error
 403 forbidden error might be due to a faulty `.htaccess` rewrite you should remove the `index.php` url you `.htaccess` file should contain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Your `config.php` should contain this

`$config['index_page'] = "";`

`$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

Comment: Now i'm getting 403 Forbidden error instead of 500 Server Error!

Comment: I don't have index.php in my url as i've used mod_rewrite!
But the access to the file is not allowed i don't know!